# Creating Linphone as a Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, linphone, xcode8.2

I'd like to recreate a linphone library as a framework library but i'm facing a problem with Apple Mach-O Linker. 
I was trying to fix this for a week but i can't. Please help me or guide me the way to fix this.I'm new with iOS app development.(I also tried to recreate with static library and add it with subproject the problem is the same).

[This](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4gtgiY3w5xyc2NoQnZsZHlyOG8) is my testing xcode project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just download your project after run i got the smae error you were taking about "Apple Mach-O Linker". i solved the problem hope it is hepful to you.

You just need to **GO >Project Target > Build Settings** then search for Bitcode. You will find Enable **Bitcode = "YES" Make it "NO"**

PFA

[image]

Comment: It works!. Thank you so much. And now I'm trying to build with a Universal but it shows me some error. Trying to fix it.

Comment: No problem. However, your framework is now building but unfortunately, some errors occur after the build process.But, you can access the frameworks. If i got time from my job schedule i will look again your project.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I'll keep trying to fix an error